# Does the Google Maps JavaScript API pricing model limits the amount of markers on a map?

Tags: google-maps-markers, servicenow

I'w working with ServiceNow and by default there's a limit of 500 markers in the map page instance, prior to updating the limit to 1500 markers I want to be sure there's no extra charge for our company.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard limit for the number of markers you are able to place on a map using the Maps JavaScript API, it depends on how much your web browser can handle.

Maps JavaScript API's [Dynamic Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#dynamic-maps) is only billed per map load or per map display. One (1) map load is counted every time a map is created with the google.maps.Map() class. Displaying multiple markers/pins will **not** add to the map load count. One map display with multiple markers would still be charged as one dynamic map count.

Please do note however that if in any case you geocode each of the addresses first using [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) and using the geocoding results to display the markers, a separate [charge for the Geocoding requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#geocoding) will be billed accordingly.

Hope this helps!